# While controller don't stop Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am encountering a problem with "**While Controller**":

This is what I do:

```
Thread Group
   -user defined variables (I have assigned 'nikitaShalom' to {})
   -while controller (the following condition:         ${__javascript(eval("'${nikitaShalom}'  !=  '${str}'")})
   -Http request (my request) 
     - JSON path extractor (to extract the value I will use in my while   controller)
```

I have pre-defined **nikitaShalom to be {}** as I said after the extraction it should get '**userArrivedNode**' then I am comparing it to **str** variable which predefined to '**userArrivedNode**' I can see that the while controller keeps going it does not stop even if I get the condition right. why is this?

Can you give me any reference about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please format the question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer for this problem, all has to be done is to change javascript to javaScript with captial 'S'.

Thnaks!